# Concatenar texto a una variable en la inicialización de un Array

Tags: autohotkey

Cómo concatenar variables del sistema como A_Desktop con texto en la misma inicialización del array, dentro de los corchetes; el segundo item resulta vacío

```
    arDirectoriesSearch := [A_Desktop, A_Desktop + "\Games"]
    MsgBox, % arDirectoriesSearch[1] ; "C:Users\user\Desktop"
    MsgBox, % arDirectoriesSearch[2] ; ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Un espacio cuando es :=

```
  arDirectoriesSearch := [A_Desktop, A_Desktop "/Games"]
```

Comment: Si ese era el error, entonces se podria considerar un error tipográfico, en cuyo caso la pregunta no es válida para este sitio y deberia ser eliminada.